# SQL-script to clean out a database completely?

Tags: sql

Can somebody help write a SQL script that can delete all the tables, and all the data from the database?

I know I can do `DROP tableName` but I want a script that could work across any Database and completely clean it.

NOTE: I do not want to delete the database itself, just empty all the tables and delete all the tables.

NOTE: I am using SQL Server Compact Edition if it matters at all.

Comment: It seems like dropping the database and just creating a new one with the same name would be more efficient.

Comment: ok- I will do that if I dont find any other easy solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this could help you   ?

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-empty-mysql-database/

Comment: so basically you would drop the database and recreate it, or am I missing something? you could've just said that without the link.

Comment: Just show that a simple google research is sometimes quicker, but yes drop it and recreate it is a good way

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a stored procedure in SQL Server that can be used for dropping all the tables in a database, like this:

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable @command1 = "DROP TABLE ?"
```

([source](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/transactsql/thread/a512be8a-376f-4fc9-8243-78dbdbe59e55/))

Comment: I am using SQL CE 4.0, and not the SQL server. So this won't work i guess.

Comment: ok. Leaving the answer here though in case it would help someone else.

Answer (score 1):

DROP databasename . Use this. this was helpfull

Comment: would this delete the .sdf file completely?

Answer (score 0):

**Delete All Tables**

--Delete All Keys

```
DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(500) DECLARE @Cursor CURSOR
SET @Cursor = CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
SELECT DISTINCT sql = 'ALTER TABLE [' + tc2.TABLE_NAME + '] DROP [' + rc1.CONSTRAINT_NAME + ']'
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS rc1
LEFT JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS tc2 ON tc2.CONSTRAINT_NAME =rc1.CONSTRAINT_NAME
OPEN @Cursor FETCH NEXT FROM @Cursor INTO @Sql
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
Exec SP_EXECUTESQL @Sql
FETCH NEXT FROM @Cursor INTO @Sql
END
CLOSE @Cursor DEALLOCATE @Cursor
GO
EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'DROP TABLE ?'
GO
```

**Delete All Stored Procedures**

```
declare @procName varchar(500)
declare cur cursor
    for select [name] from sys.objects where type = 'p'
open cur

fetch next from cur into @procName
      while @@fetch_status = 0
      begin
            if @procName <> 'DeleteAllProcedures'
                  exec('drop procedure ' + @procName)
                  fetch next from cur into @procName
      end

close cur
deallocate cur
```

**Delete All Views**

```
    declare @procName varchar(500)
    declare cur cursor
        for select [name] from sys.objects where type = 'v'
    open cur

    fetch next from cur into @procName
          while @@fetch_status = 0
          begin
                      exec('drop view ' + @procName)
                      fetch next from cur into @procName
          end
    close cur
    deallocate cur
```

**Delete All Functions**

```
declare @procName varchar(500)
declare cur cursor
    for select [name] from sys.objects where type = 'fn'
open cur

fetch next from cur into @procName
      while @@fetch_status = 0
      begin
                  exec('drop function ' + @procName)
                  fetch next from cur into @procName
      end

close cur
deallocate cur
```

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
    TRUNCATE DATABASE
```

I hope it works

Comment: I dont think you can use TRUNCATE command on database, only on tables.